# How to create views tabs in D8?

Tags: views, 8, routes

I can't get views tabs to work in D8, following the exact UI procedure that does work in D7.

To be more precise, in D8 at /mypage I see no tabs at all, and at /mypage/tab2 and /mypage/tab3 I do see tabs "tab2" and tab3" but no "MyDefaultTab".

In D7, I see all 3 tabs when viewing any of the 3 URLs.

The following procedure works to create a Views page with tabs in D7 on simplytest.me, but does not work for D8 beta 15:

- Manage > Structure > Views > Add new view
- View name = "Myview"; Show "Content" of type "all"; save and edit.
- Add page display; name="MyPage"; path = "mypage"; menu = "Normal menu entry" with menutitle ="MyPage" and parent="" (its default value) and weight=0;
- Add page display; name="MyDefaultTab"; path="mypage/defaulttab"; menu = "Default menu tab" with menutitle ="DefaultTab" and parent menu item ="Already exists";
- Add page display; name="tab2"; path="mypage/tab2"; menu="Menu tab" with menutitle="Tab2" and parent ="" (its default value) and weight=0.
- Add page display; name="tab3"; path="mypage/tab3"; menu="Menu tab" with menutitle="Tab3" and parent ="" (its default value) and weight=0.

Is this a D8 bug, or am I missing something?

Things I have tried (all made no difference, good or bad):

- Selecting "MyPage" (the non default but sensible seeming value) in the "parent" drop down for tab2 and tab3 (there are more menu options available in D8 than D7).
- Selecting "Normal menu item" instead of "Already exists" for the parent menu item of the default tab.
- Configuration > Performance > Clear All Caches

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpuRdzyK3jI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have just created a views page with tabs. Following are the instructions.
Add a views display of type page

1. Set its path to "/test"
   Then its menu option: Select "Default menu tab" and on next screen    select "Already exist" under the "parent menu item".
2. Then adds another page display
   set its path to "test/tab1"
   and in its menu option: select "Menu tab" and save.

Visit the "/test" page and both tabs appear.
Hope it may help you.

Comment: You're right Ahmad, that works. Thanks! It therefore seems that Drupal 8 uses a different approach to Drupal 7, where the "default menu tab" was used for a kind of dummy page display whose contents were mostly ignored but which did create the default tab. In D8 this dummy page display is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your tabs displayed **/tabsparent/tab1**, **/tabsparent/tab2**, etc.., without **/tabsparent** default tab, please visit https://www.drupal.org/node/2693069#comment-12025897 page.

Just import configuration files on the link with ready to use view and see the difference.