# How to add tab page in views?

Tags: views, 8

I am using Drupal 8.0.0. I try to add a custom tab page (view page, using views) to my custom content type.

I searched a lot, most sources related to D7 and their instructions not work in D8. It took me a few hours to test tab but tabs not appear in D8.

I also followed the instructions at [How to create views tabs in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173306/how-to-create-views-tabs-in-d8) but that didn't work.

By the way, I can get tab by following instruction of https://www.drupal.org/node/2116767, but my question is:how to add tag page (or tab menu) in D8 Views (core version 8.0.0 and above), not by custom module.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad's answer to my question that you reference, works just fine for me in a simplytest sandbox with D8.0.1.

You now have to give titles to the tabs, but they can be anything you like.

I suggest you check again in a clean simplytest sandbox. And remember to save the view - that's the easiest part to overlook.