# Using one exposed filter on different date fields

Tags: views

So been looking at this for a bit now and nothing springing to mind so question and advice needed. On Drupal 8.

**What I want:**
I have a content type with three date fields (Date A, Date B and Date C). Using a view I can create an exposed filter to filter dates between ranges, before, after, etc on say Date A. I can do the same for the other date fields.

I would like to restrict it to one date field at a time. So select the dates for Date A **OR** Date B **OR** Date C but never more than one date field.

**Question**
Sounds simple. I cannot find a simple way to do this so unless I have missed the obvious am going to have to create a module. Before I look into that and start the ball rolling are there any existing solutions I have missed?

Assuming there is no easy way my thought was to create a new module.This would allow one date input and then a select box to choose which field to perform the operation on.

I have not yet looked at this in depth so as to using JS/AJAX to achieve this or a PHP solution (Class or hook), I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: And before it is suggested, yes I realise that it will probably mean I have to create my own exposed views filter - just want to check there is nothing obvious I am missing.

Comment: Please note it is the functionality above I am after, not a close approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Create three different views, each with one exposed filter. Use css class to control visibility, use a bit of javascript to move around.

Refer [How to create views tabs in D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173306/how-to-create-views-tabs-in-d8)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Whilst tabs work but not what I want. One view with exposed filter. Guess I will be writing my own exposed filter!

Comment: So only way to get exactly what I want is to create a custom filter.